# How to write regular expression to use re.split in python

Tags: python, regex

I have  a string like this:

```
----------

FT Weekend

----------

Why do we run marathons?
Are marathons and cycling races about more than exercise? What does the 
literature of endurance tell us about our thirst for self-imposed hardship?
```

I want to delete the part from `----------` to the next `----------` included.

I have been using `re.sub`:

```
pattern =r"-+\n.+\n-+"
re.sub(pattern, '', thestring)
```

Comment: could you be more precise

Answer (score 4):

```
pattern =r"-+\n.+?\n-+"
re.sub(pattern, '', thestring,flags=re.DOTALL)
```

Just use `DOTALL` flag.The problem with your regex was that by default `.` does not match `\n`.So you need to explicitly add a flag `DOTALL` making it match `\n`.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hR7tH4/24

or

```
pattern =r"-+\n[\s\S]+?\n-+"
re.sub(pattern, '', thestring)
```

if you dont want to add a flag

Comment: @stribizhev yups .make it non greedy

Answer (score 2):

Your regex doesn't match the expected part because `.+` doesn't capture new line character. you can use `re.DOTALL` flag to forced `.` to match newlines or `re.S`.but instead of that You can use a negated character class :

```
>>> print re.sub(r"-+[^-]+-+", '', s)
''

Why do we run marathons?
Are marathons and cycling races about more than exercise? What does the 
literature of endurance tell us about our thirst for self-imposed hardship? 
>>>
```

Or more precise you can do:

```
>>> print re.sub(r"-+[^-]+-+[^\w]+", '', s)
'Why do we run marathons?
Are marathons and cycling races about more than exercise? What does the 
literature of endurance tell us about our thirst for self-imposed hardship? 
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your regex (`-+\n.+\n-+`) is that `.` matches any character *but* a newline, and that it is too greedy (`.+`), and can span across multiple `-------` entities.

You can use the following regex:

```
pattern = r"(?s)-+\n.+?\n-+"
```

The `(?s)` singleline option makes `.` match any character including newline.
The `.+?` pattern will match 1 or more characters but as few as possible to match up to the next `----`.

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/z0ubDl)

For a more profound cleanup, I'd recommend:

```
pattern = r"(?s)\s*-+\n.+?\n-+\s*"
```

See [another demo](https://ideone.com/6Esjre)

Comment: Not sure if you have single quotes, or not, I included them into my 2nd recommended regex.